# cannot insert data in codeigniter 4

Tags: exception, insert, codeigniter-4

I want to insert registration data, I followed the existing tutorial, but got an error exception.

```
$users = new UsersModel();
$data = [
    'name' => $this->request->getPost('name'),
    'email' => $this->request->getPost('email'),
    'password' => password_hash($this->request->getPost('password'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT) 
];

$users->insert($data);
```

My Model:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class UsersModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = "users";
    protected $primarykey = "id";
    protected $returnType = "object";
    protected $useTimestamps = true;
    protected $allowedFields = ['name', 'email', 'password'];
}
```

throw the exception:

```
mysqli_sql_exception #1054

Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is

```
mysqli_sql_exception #1054

Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list'
```

Which strongly suggests that it is expecting a column called **updated_at**.

You have set `protected $useTimestamps = true;`

So as per the documentation:

> **$useTimestamps**
>
> This boolean value determines whether the current date is
> automatically added to all inserts and updates. If true, will set the
> current time in the format specified by $dateFormat. This requires
> that the table have columns named ‘created_at’ and ‘updated_at’ in the
> appropriate data type.

So you need to create the columns **created_at** and **updated_at**